# Quickest way to make schema of objects in Array of Object uniform

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am having a **big** array (length:10k) of coordinates (`rawData = [x,y1,y2,y3,...]`) as follows:

```
rawData = [
    {x: 1, y1: 1, y2: 13, y3: 2},
    {x: 2, y1: 2, y2: 23, y3: 2},
    {x: 3, y1: 3, y2: 33, y3: 2, y4: 4},
    {x: 4, y1: 4, y2: 43, y3: 2, y5: 5},
]
```

As it can be seen, the objects in this array are not consistent because of varying `schema`.

**What is the fastest way to make this array consistent, so that they have same `schema`?**

If the object is not having any given key, it can be initialized with a default value (say 0) to make `processedData` as follows:

```
processedData = [
    {x: 0, y1: 1, y2: 13, y3: 2, y4: 0, y5: 0},
    {x: 1, y1: 2, y2: 23, y3: 2, y4: 0, y5: 0},
    {x: 2, y1: 3, y2: 33, y3: 2, y4: 4, y5: 0},
    {x: 3, y1: 4, y2: 43, y3: 2, y4: 0, y5: 5},
]
```

Edit: I am expecting a solution without needing to loop the entire array because this array is huge, or some solution optimized for that.

Answer (score 3):

You may first create a skeleton object from iterating over the original object and collecting the keys.

Then, with the help of `Object.assign`, you can combine overwrite the skeleton's values with the values the original objects have and rest of those will be intact.

See the demo below:

```js
var rawData = [
    {x: 1, y1: 1, y2: 13, y3: 2},
    {x: 2, y1: 2, y2: 23, y3: 2},
    {x: 3, y1: 3, y2: 33, y3: 2, y4: 4},
    {x: 4, y1: 4, y2: 43, y3: 2, y5: 5},
];

var def = {};

// Create the skeleton object
rawData.forEach(item => {
  Object.keys(item).forEach(k => {
    def[k] = 0;
  })
})

// Extend the skeleton with original data
var res = rawData.map(item => Object.assign({}, def, item))
console.log(res);
```

Comment: +1. However, I was expecting a solution without needing to loop the entire array.  For example converting it to string and gettting the keys or something. But good answer anyway.

Comment: @dasfdsa -- If you know what's the highest index of `y`, it can be done. But without it, you will have to go through the entire array.

Comment: But that would only work if keys are named as yi. For my case keys are not  `yi`. I used `yi` just to make the problem simpler to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.map` and template object

```js
const rawData = [
    {x: 1, y1: 1, y2: 13, y3: 2},
    {x: 2, y1: 2, y2: 23, y3: 2},
    {x: 3, y1: 3, y2: 33, y3: 2, y4: 4},
    {x: 4, y1: 4, y2: 43, y3: 2, y5: 5},
];

const temp = rawData
.reduce((t, o) => ({...t, ...o}), {});

Object.keys(temp).forEach(k => temp[k] = 0);

const result = rawData.map(o => ({...temp, ...o}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a single loop for the data and update the keys if an unknown keys is found.

```js
var rawData = [{ x: 1, y1: 1, y2: 13, y3: 2 }, { x: 2, y1: 2, y2: 23, y3: 2 }, { x: 3, y1: 3, y2: 33, y3: 2, y4: 4 }, { x: 4, y1: 4, y2: 43, y3: 2, y5: 5 }],
    keys = [],
    processedData = rawData.reduce((r, o) => {
        var temp = Object.assign({}, o);
        Object.keys(o).forEach(k => {
            if (keys.includes(k)) {
                return;
            }
            r.forEach(p => Object.assign(p, { [k]: 0 }));
            keys.push(k);
        });
        r.push(temp)
        return r;
    }, []);
    
console.log(processedData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you do not know what fields you will need. In order to find out what fields you will need you will have to take a look at all the elements of the array.

For example your suggestion of converting the array to string and parse it accordingly could work, but would be EXTREMELY inefficient, as string operations tend to be slow, not to mention that when you convert your array to string, you are taking a look at all the elements anyway.

Since you absolutely need to take a look at all elements to find out all the possible fields, you will need to loop your array twice: first you gather the keys and then you apply your needed changes:

```
//Gathering keys
var keys = [];

for (var index = 0; index < rawData.length; index++) {
    for (var key in rawData[index]) keys.push(key);
}

//Applying them
for (var index = 0; index < rawData.length; index++) {
    for (var key in keys)
        if (typeof rawData[index][key] === "undefined") rawData[index][key] = 0;
}
```